# How to obtain an ANOVA for a RCBD using R?

Tags: r, anova

I have analyzing the following data, where Days are the blocks and Solution are the treatments. I have tried the following R code:

```
Growth = c(13, 16, 5, 22, 24, 4, 18, 17, 1, 39, 44, 22) #Data was inputted for Day1, then Day2, Day3, Day4

Days = factor(c(rep(1,3), rep(2,3), rep(3,3), rep(4,3)))
Days
 [1] 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4
Levels: 1 2 3 4

Solution = factor(c(rep(1,4), rep(2,4), rep(3,4)))
Solution
 [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
Levels: 1 2 3

Bact.df = data.frame(Solution, Days, Growth)
Bact.df
   Solution Days Growth

1         1    1     13
2         1    1     16
3         1    1      5
4         1    2     22
5         2    2     24
6         2    2      4
7         2    3     18 
8         2    3     17
9         3    3      1
10        3    4     39
11        3    4     44
12        3    4     22
```

However, the output for Solution is incorrect because Solution 1 should apply to the Growth values 13, 22, 18, 39. Solution 2 should apply to 16, 24, 17, 44. Solution 3 should apply to 5, 4, 1, 22.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `Solution = factor(rep(1:3, 4))`. and `Days=factor(rep(1:4, each=3))`

Comment: Better: `expand.grid(Solution=1:3, Days=1:4)`